# replacing xml values and attributes with json file in php

Tags: php, json, xml, domdocument

I am trying to change an xml file. The sample file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<country>
<display>
    <identification>
        <country>nl</country>
        <identifier>ABC01</identifier>
    </identification>
</display>
<region>
    <publicationTime>2018-04-18T09:45:00Z</publicationTime>
    <publicationCreator>
        <identifier>ABC01</identifier>
    </publicationCreator>
    <tableLoc id="ABC01_SITE_TABLE" version="14"/>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC01" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC02" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC03" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC04" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC17" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC19" version="9"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC18" version="9"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC15" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC09" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
        <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC011" version="7"/>
    </measurements>
</region>
</country>
```

first of all i needed to change the tag value of the 2 identifiers from

```
<identifier>ABC01</identifier>
```

to

```
<identifier>NLNDW</identifier>
```

which succeeded. then i had to change the attribute of

```
<tableLoc id="ABC01_SITE_TABLE" version="14"/>
```

to

```
<tableLoc id="NDW_01_MT" version="14"/>
```

finally i need to overwrite all siteloc attribute versions with the corresponding id's from a json file:

```
{
"ABC01": {
    "ABC01_ABC01": 9,
    "ABC01_ABC02": 7,
    "ABC01_ABC03": 4,
    "ABC01_ABC04": 1,
    "ABC01_ABC05": 2,
    "ABC01_ABC06": 16,
    "ABC01_ABC07": 3,
    "ABC01_ABC08": 8,
    "ABC01_ABC09": 7,
    "ABC01_ABC10": 6,
    "ABC01_ABC11": 4,
    "ABC01_ABC12": 3,
    "ABC01_ABC13": 2,
    "ABC01_ABC14": 2,
    "ABC01_ABC15": 2,
    "ABC01_ABC16": 3,
    "ABC01_ABC17": 5,
    "ABC01_ABC18": 5,
    "ABC01_ABC19": 2,
    "ABC01_ABC20": 3,
    "ABC01_ABC21": 5,
    "ABC01_ABC22": 39,
    "ABC01_ABC23": 23,
    "ABC01_ABC24": 13,
    "ABC01_ABC25": 1,
    "ABC01_ABC26": 1,
    "ABC01_ABC27": 3
},
"ABC02": {
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 3,
    "ABC02_ABC02": 2
},
"VWY09": {
    "VWY09_VWY10": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY11": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY12": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY13": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY14": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY15": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY16": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY17": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY18": 1,
    "VWY09_VWY19": 1
},
"GAD02": {
    "GAD02_XRZ01": 2,
    "GAD02_XRZ02": 2,
    "GAD02_XRZ03": 2,
    "GAD02_XRZ04": 2,
    "GAD02_XRZ05": 2,
    "GAD02_XRZ06": 2,
    "GAD02_XRZ07": 2,
    "GAD02_XRZ08": 2
}
}
```

so for instance

```
<measurements>
    <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC03" version="7"/>
</measurements>
```

needs to become:

```
<measurements>
    <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC03" version="4"/>
</measurements>
```

my code thusfar:

```
$identification = new DomDocument;
$identification2 = new DomDocument;
$identification3 = new DomDocument;
$identification_node = $identification ->createElement('identification');
$identification_node2 = $identification2  ->createElement('publicationCreator');
$identification_node3 = $identification3 ->createElement('tableLoc');

// Add some children
$identification_node->appendChild($identification->createElement('country', 'nl'));
$identification_node->appendChild($identification->createElement('identifier', 'NLNDW'));
$identification_node2->appendChild($identification2->createElement('identifier     ', 'NLNDW'));
$newnode3 = $identification3->appendChild($identification_node3);
$newnode3->setAttribute("align", "left");

$identification->appendChild($identification_node);
$identification2->appendChild($identification_node2);

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath1 = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath2 = new DOMXpath($dom);


$nodelist = $xpath->query('/country/display/identification');
$nodelist1 = $xpath1->query('/country/region/publicationCreator');
$oldnode = $nodelist->item(0);
$oldnode1 = $nodelist1->item(0);

$newnode = $dom->importNode($identification->documentElement, true);
$newnode1 = $dom->importNode($identification2->documentElement, true);

$oldnode->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $oldnode);
$oldnode1->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode1, $oldnode1);

echo $dom->saveXML($dom);
$dom->save('result.xml');
```

I know how to iterate through the xml but i have no idea how to find the matching siteloc id attribute in the json file and overwrite the siteloc version attribute with the version from the json.

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating 4 different DOM documents? To replace the data you just need one, load the original data and replace it.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
// load the original data
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate any "identifier" element node
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//identifier') as $identifier) {
  // change its content
  $identifier->textContent = 'NLNDW';
}
// iterate any "id" attribute of an "tableLoc" node 
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//tableLoc/@id') as $tableLocId) {
  // change its value
  $tableLocId->value = 'NDW_01_MT';
}

// decode json, force arrays
$map = json_decode($json, TRUE);

// iterate any "siteLoc" element node in the document
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//siteLoc[@id]') as $siteLocation) {
  // read the "id"attribute
  $id = $siteLocation->getAttribute('id');
  // the json seems to be grouped by the first part
  $groupId = strstr($id, '_', TRUE);
  // check if here is a new value
  if (isset($map[$groupId][$id])) {
    // change the version attribute
    $siteLocation->setAttribute('version', $map[$groupId][$id]);
  } 
}

// output/save the modified document
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Comment: To answer your question, because this is my first take at PHP. your solution worked perfectly for the xml mentioned in the question, I tried it on another xml with namespaces, adjusted the php script and to my suprise it didn't work anymore. I could not figure out why it doesn't work. After some searching i found out i have to use getElementsByTagNameNS. I didn't succeed yet to transform the xml thgough.

Comment: register a namespace prefix on the $xpath object and use it in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files such as replacing node and attribute text. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class, requiring the extension enabled in .ini file.

However, first your relatively flat JSON needs to be converted to XML which PHP can build and then the XSLT script will reference recursively to map over needed site location values across documents using `document()` function. Be sure to save both XML files (original source and json-converted) in same directory.

**PHP** *(JSON Converted XML; only place where loops are used)*

```
$data = json_decode($site_json, TRUE);

// Create a DOM document 
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Create the root element of XML tree
$root = $dom->createElement("site_locations");
$root = $dom->appendChild($root);

// Iterate json elements for child nodes
foreach ($data as $outer) {      
    foreach ($outer as $k=>$v) {  
        $node = $dom->createElement('site');
        $root->appendChild($node);
        $node->setAttribute("id", $k);
        $node->setAttribute("version", $v);
    }
}

// Output XML content to screen
echo $dom->saveXML();
// <?xml version="1.0"?>
// <site_locations>
//   <site id="ABC01_ABC01" version="9"/>
//   <site id="ABC01_ABC02" version="7"/>
//   <site id="ABC01_ABC03" version="4"/>
//   <site id="ABC01_ABC04" version="1"/>
//   <site id="ABC01_ABC05" version="2"/>
//   <site id="ABC01_ABC06" version="16"/>
//   ...

// Output XML content to file
file_put_contents("SiteLocationsLookups.xml", $dom->saveXML());
```

**XSLT Script** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="identifier">
    <xsl:copy>NLNDW</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tableLoc">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:attribute name="id">NDW_01_MT</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@version"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="siteLoc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="curr_id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="version">
         <xsl:value-of select="document('SiteLocationsLookups.xml')//site[@id=$curr_id]/@version"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(processing final XML)*

```
// Load XML and XSLT files
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');              // REFERENCES JSON CONVERTED XML

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// Save output to file
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXml);
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<country>
  <display>
    <identification>
      <country>nl</country>
      <identifier>NLNDW</identifier>
    </identification>
  </display>
  <region>
    <publicationTime>2018-04-18T09:45:00Z</publicationTime>
    <publicationCreator>
      <identifier>NLNDW</identifier>
    </publicationCreator>
    <tableLoc id="NDW_01_MT" version="14" />
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC01" version="9" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC02" version="7" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC03" version="4" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC04" version="1" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC17" version="5" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC19" version="2" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC18" version="5" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC15" version="2" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC09" version="7" />
    </measurements>
    <measurements>
      <siteLoc id="ABC01_ABC011" version="" />
    </measurements>
  </region>
</country>
```

Comment: your code works perfect but when i try it with a different xml (with namespaces) i doesn't seem to work when i delete all namespaces it works. I wasn't aware there could be an issue when namespaces are in the xml. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Absolutely, namespaces affect XML parsing and XSLT processing! Always, always, always, include them in original post. But I see you found a solution but yes, this can be updated to handle namespaces.

Comment: yes, lesson learned. I am qurious though, can you give me a tip on how to adjust your code in order to handle namespaces?.

Comment: Please post your XML with namespaces.

Comment: Add namespace definitions on the `xsl:stylesheet` element and use the prefix in Xpath expressions as needed.